# Transfering Circuit from Veroboard to Breadboard

Tags: breadboard, stripboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip board (Veroboard) Layout Circuit to breadboard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/strip-board-veroboard-layout-circuit-to-breadboard)

How can I transfer the following circuit from veroboard to breadboard? I don't know much about veroboard as how it has internal connections. Can somebody help me in transfering this circuit to breadboard?

[image]

Comment: Is this for the telephone bug again? If so why not just follow the schematic you posted initially [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33550/building-a-telephone-spy)?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different types of veroboard. This one has all solder joints on a row connected. That would limit your board to maximum 10 nets, but it's common to cut rows in two or more separate parts.

Connections on a solderless breadboard are completely different; they have rows of 5 connections instead of the 14 here, and a couple of long rails for power.

Because of the difference in layout I wouldn't try to convert one into the other, but go back to the schematic and layout the breadboard from that. (You *do* have a schematic, don't you?) If a schematic is built up logically it may be easier to transform that into a breadboard layout than to start from what you now have.

Comment: ...or you can try to extract the schematic from the veroboard

Comment: @clabacchio - Might work reasonably well here, all components are marked, but you can't see the orientation of the diodes, for instance.

Comment: heh right :) but the pins have different symbols, it may also be an indication

Comment: @Steven - the schematic is [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33550/building-a-telephone-spy).

Comment: @Oli - Yeah, I just read your other comment. Thanks.